# Add togther HH:MM form multiple field to give a total of hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, time, addition

can someone please assist, i would like to add together multiple fields containing time in HH:MM format. E.g. I have 4 fields first field contains 08:30, second field contains 12:30, the third field contains 13:30 and the fourth field contains 17:30. i would like the total time to add upto 8 hours (8:00). 
currently have this code ...

```
function Min2HHMM(nMinutes) {
// convert minutes to HH:MM string and returns formatted time string
return util.printf("%,001.0f:%,202.0f", Math.floor(nMinutes / 60), nMinutes % 60);

}

var T1 = this.getField("Start_Mon_01").value;
var T2 = this.getField("Finish_Mon_01").value;
var T3 = this.getField("Start_Mon_02").value;
var T4 = this.getField("Finish_Mon_02").value;


var start = T1.split(":");
var startmins1 = parseInt(start[0] * 60) + parseInt(start[1]);

var finish = T2.split(":");
var finishmins1 = parseInt(finish[0] * 60) + parseInt(finish[1]);

var start = T3.split(":");
var startmins2 = parseInt(start[0] * 60) + parseInt(start[1]);

var finish = T4.split(":");
var finishmins2 = parseInt(finish[0] * 60) + parseInt(T4[1]);

var timeDiff = finishmins1 - startmins1 + finishmins2 - startmins2;

event.value = isNaN(timeDiff)?" ": Min2HHMM(timeDiff);
```

Help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: **(1)** Where/how is `util` defined? **(2)** What is your actual output? **(3)** You should edit your question to include an MVCE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - this would take care of **(1)**.

Comment: You have an error in `finishmins2` calculation: you use `T4[1]` instead of `finish[1]`. https://jsfiddle.net/0xq0rnwj/